# What time do you leave Sam today?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

How to ask politely in English if someone is going to leave or drop off someone ??

For example: What time will you be going to drop Sam today?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some polite (or at least, polite enough) possibilities:

- What time will you be dropping Sam off today?
- What time will you be dropping off Sam today?
- What time will you be bringing Sam over today?
- What time will you be bringing Sam round today?

You can also substitute *later* for *today*.